# A number of forbidden errors (403) which causes failures in cosmosdb

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, http-status-code-403, azure-durable-functions

Seeing a flood of 403 Substatus: 1014 issues in cosmos database while writing new documents and replacing existing document item in container. RU is set as 100000 and the container has its own provisioned throughput. The total memory used by the problematic container is 5Kb and totally there are about ~300k documents.

```
Response status code does not indicate success: Forbidden (403); Substatus: 1014; ActivityId: ; Reason: ();
```

Making bulk write/replace requests.

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace or details of the error, which SDK are you using and which is the snippet of the operation?

Comment: Also, please be mindful of tags: the `[cosmos]` tag has nothing to do with Cosmos DB (and is spelled out clearly in the tag description).

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of the errors, it looks like that code means that you are exceeding the storage for your Partition Key value. Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#logical-partitions, the documents with a particular Partition Key value cannot exceed 20Gb:

> There is no limit to the number of logical partitions in your container. Each logical partition can store up to 20GB of data. Good partition key choices have a wide range of possible values. For example, in a container where all items contain a foodGroup property, the data within the Beef Products logical partition can grow up to 20 GB